# C# explorer-like picture grid with Usercontrols

Tags: c#, grid, gallery, picturebox

I need to build a Picture-Gallery-ish thing which displays about 3000 thumbnails in a Windows-Explorer "large icons" Style.

So I went for the flowLayoutPanel, to which I add an Usercontrol for every .jpg in a given Folder using a foreach-loop.

I am facing two Problems now:

1) It is extremely slow. On my 4 GHz Machine, the Form takes about 55 seconds to load

2) It is buggy somehow: After scrolling through half of the Pictures, the flowLayoutPanel is just blank.

I would appreciate any suggestions concerning either improvement of the current solution, or an idea for a completely new one.

Thanks in Advance,

Jann

Comment: Did you consider using threads for the walking through the directory? Also, you could load an initial subset of the files and re-load them in the background (maybe threaded as well) as the y-position of the scroll pane changes. The blank panel sounds like it fails to re-draw the canvas. Try to call the redraw method manually to see if that solves it.

Comment: Adding __3000__ user controls, maybe with more controls on each, adding up to at least __6000__ controls,  is clearly __over the limit__ of what Winforms is good at.  - I would preload the thumbnails into an ImageList (if 256x256 is good enough) and display them in a ListView in LargeIcon view.. This way only __one__ control is used. Also: Explorer does this only so fast if the thumbs.db file is current.

Comment: @TaW Thanks a lot! Using Listview Takes about a tenth of the Time (in my case about 4 seconds) to load, which is absolutely fine for my purposes. Since my program will be used with just one Set of Pictures per User, would it make Sense to somehow create a "Thumb-Database" in an initialization process?

Comment: Why not? Maybe zipping the thumbnails would speed up the 2nd loads..